# HTML in square brackets -> output as normal HTML

Tags: feeds, theming, input-formats

We do import (using Feeds_ex) some data into Drupal (we do not control data-source we use to import data) and these data contains HTML in a brackets.

so far I have found these 3 brackets:

```
 1. [b]bla bla bla[/b]
 2. [i]my text[/i]
 3. [url=http://www.google.com/[/url]
```

I'm wondering if there is a good approach to deal with these values:

```
 - Convert them during import?
 - Somehow define in Drupal that these tag are equal to <b>, <i> or <a
   href>?
```

At the very end I want to output these data as HTML.

I would be happy to get any suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's [BBCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode).

One option would be to simply install the [BBCode](https://www.drupal.org/project/bbcode) module, which contains a BBCode filter. You can then apply that filter to the text format you're using for the body field, and it'll be converted to HTML automatically when rendered.